# How to get the `< ... >` syntax on an object?

Tags: object, raku, calling-convention

In Raku: when I create an object with a CALL-ME method, I would like to use the `< ... >` syntax for the signature instead of `( '...' )` when `...` is a Str.
In the documentation, there is an example of creating an operator, which is an ordinary Raku sub with a special syntax. This sort of sub automatically converts `< ... >` into a Str.
For example, if I have

```
use v6.d;
class A {
   has %.x;
   method CALL-ME( Str:D $key ) { say %!x{ $key } }
}

my A $q .= new( :x( <one two three> Z=> 1..* ) );
$q('two');
$q<two>;
```

But this produces

```
2
Type A does not support associative indexing.
  in block <unit> at test.raku line 10
```

Comment: cf [Something is wrong with handles](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/c7l3d9/something_is_wrong_with_handles/).

Comment: Changing `has %.x;` to `has %.x handles <AT-KEY>;` means your example works. This follows logically from Liz's comment in the discussion I linked. But, based on what AJS said in that thread, I imply no warranties on the general fitness of this solution.

Comment: @raiph, the r/rakulang thread is closed, but I agree with what you said there about `class Foo is Hash`.  The `new` issue can be solved with `method new(|c) { self.Any::new(|c) }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An answer based on @raiph's comment:

You need to implement the [`AT-KEY`](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#method_AT-KEY) method on your type.

You can do so directly like this:

```raku
class A {
   has %.x;
   method CALL-ME( Str:D $key ) { say %!x{ $key } }
   method AT-KEY($key) { self.($key) }
}
```

Or you can do so by delegating `AT-KEY` to `%!x` using the [`handles`](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#trait_handles) trait:

```raku
class A {
   has %.x handles <AT-KEY>;
   method CALL-ME( Str:D $key ) { say %!x{ $key } }
}
```

Comment: @raiph but if I'm reading the reddit thread correctly, neither your AJS's suggested change nor yours would change the semantics of `handles <AT-KEY>`, would they?  (It's just about `handles *` or `handles '*'`, right?)

Comment: In the question, I used `has %.x` as the minimal structure. In the code I'm working on, the hash does exist a couple of layers down, so a `handles` is not really an option. The method AT-KEY is the more generic route.

Comment: @codesections Correct.